# Is it possible to add this line "as is" in HTML markup?

Tags: javascript, html, .net, json

Is it possible to add this JavaScript and JSON expressions "as is" in HTML markup?

```
CONTRATE > 50 && SALINC <= 50 || RETAGE >= 50

{ "CONTRATE": 0, "SALINC": 0, "MARSTATUS": "single", "SPOUSEDOB": "1970-01-01" }
```

So that I can load it into XmlDocument .NET object?

It could be anything (html tag attribute, html tag content...), just have to be part of HTML and be xml-valid.

Comment: For json you could use JSON.stringify(json)

Comment: lots of ways to do it

Comment: Sorry but you didn't understand the question... )

Answer (score 1):

You can stash text inside `<script>` tags that are explicitly marked as *not* being JavaScript:

```
<script id="expression" type="text/not-javascript">
CONTRATE > 50 && SALINC <= 50 || RETAGE >= 50
</script>

<script id="stash" type="text/not-javascript">
{ "CONTRATE": 0, "SALINC": 0, "MARSTATUS": "single", "SPOUSEDOB": "1970-01-01" }
</script>
```

You can then find the `<script>` element by its id and use `innerHTML` to extract the contents.

The browser won't pay any attention to the content, other than to look for the string `</script>`, so avoid that.

Comment: You are right the HTML file doesn't break... however, and I forgot to mention it, we need to load such file into XmlDocument object, it will be customizable template and do some processing and rendering. Loading into XmlDocument fails even with these script sections.

Comment: @monstro OK, well maybe you shouldn't have included "HTML Markup" so prominently in your question :)

Comment: Why not? That is exactly what I am interested in accomplishing

Comment: Well perhaps I don't know what  you mean by "load into XmlDocument object". *What* do you need to load - that JSON or the JavaScript expression you posted? How exactly are they supposed to be included in the document object?

Comment: XmlDocument load means: var xmlDoc = new XmlDocument(); xmlDoc.Load(filePath); 

need to load the entire HTML (that has to be valid XML)

Comment: @monstro well HTML and XML are not the same thing.

Answer (score 0):

Make it a content of `code` tag, `pre` tag or `textarea`.

Answer (score -1):

The first line will break layouts because of the greater-than and less-than characters.  You'll need to use `&gt;` and `&lt;`.

```
CONTRATE &gt; 50 && SALINC &lt;= 50 || RETAGE &gt;= 50
```

The second line should be fine.

Comment: that's the point, that's why the title says "as is", this validation is defined by power users, and has to be pure JS-compliant